# Change event from textbox html control is canceling the Click event from the html button (live events)

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

Can anyone help?

I have a change event on a textbox and a click event on a button - all html.

Now if I click the button, the click event happens - great!

But I if change something in the textbox and then click the button, the event from the Change event happens which is great but I never get the click event in the button.

This is my jQuery, is there a way around this? I am lost.

```
    $('#myTextbox').live('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.aspx/GetDate",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert('the date is ' + msg.d);
            }
        });


    });

    $('#myButton').live('click', function() {
        alert('i am in click');

    });
```

**EDIT**

I have created a really simple html form and sure enough the click event doesn't fire if the change fires first - actually in this example I have used blur event; but its the same:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#htmlbutton').bind('click', function() {

            alert('i am in click');

        });



        $('#htmltextbox').bind('blur', function() {

            alert('in blur');

        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div>
        <input id="htmlbutton" type="button" value="button" /><input id="htmltextbox" type="text" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you create an example page on jsFiddle for example? It could be anything really. Are you sure the form isn't submitting? Maybe you should cancel the click event by returning false in the end..

Comment: well yes i am pretty sure its not submitting... i have alert('i am in click'); in there... and as i say if i don't put anything in the textbox then the change event doesn't occur BUT thenn i do get the click event on the button

Comment: I've just confirmed your problem. I'd like to make it a little clearer, that you go right from typing to clicking the button. That's when the click event doesn't happen.

Comment: +1 for teaching me something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your alert is squashing the button click event. If instead of alerting, you change the color of both elements, you'll see that both events get fired.

What happens is the blur/change event gets fired as soon as your mouse button goes down on the button. Since there's an alert, you have to go and click it off and it never registers the button up on the button, which is what you need for a click event to fire.

The ajax should have finished and gone onto the next event. Unless the call came back so quickly that it squashed the click even anyway.

Comment: As I explained, in order for a click even to fire, your mouse has to go down and then back up. You can confirm that if you just hold your mouse down on the button and then drag it away, the click event doesn't fire. Well the same thing happened here. It registered mouse down, but then the alert came up. I presume that you then moved the mouse away clicked ok. The alert dialog is synchronous, so all javascript execution stops. Then the mouse up is never registered.